# iOS - Crash in "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an on_unfair_lock"

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode-server

We have an Xcode server, running our CI.
When we run multiple instances of UI tests (more than 1 pipeline with UI tests running at the same time), our tests crash with following log.

It's happening since Xcode 10, everything worked till then. :-/

It seems like a crash in cookie-saving Apple service, does anyone have any work-around?

```
    Process:               appname [31396]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F41FEDC4-A8B2-4880-BA36-FC2ECDD27CDB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC70D032-0062-446E-8779-0E9C6A98DF43/appname.app/appname
Identifier:            appname
Version:               4.1.3 (4.1.3.9)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [15300]
Responsible:           appname [31396]
User ID:               501


Date/Time:             2018-12-03 13:18:16.040 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4E4553D0-0BA7-6F91-207B-F77A4E80B531


Time Awake Since Boot: 3300000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: diskcookies

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 572.2 - Device: pipeline_simulator_369641 - Runtime: iOS 12.0 (16A366) - DeviceType: iPhone SE
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: diskcookies
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001148c55e2 _os_unfair_lock_recursive_abort + 23
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001148c5710 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 226
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001100d01d2 lookUpImpOrForward + 78
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001100dd814 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b236749 _CFXNotificationPost + 105
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b235782 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 130
6   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x000000010abcd9ff DiskCookieStorage::writeFileCompletely0(DiskCookieStorage*, FilePathStat*, MemoryCookies const*, __CFData const*, TracerData*, int) + 995
7   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x000000010abcdbc2 DiskCookieStorage::_asyncWriteFileCompletely(void*) + 220
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001144ee587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001144faf87 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 94
10  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x000000010abcecbe DiskCookieStorage::syncStorageWithCompletionLocked(unsigned char, void () block_pointer) + 3278
11  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x000000010abc359f invocation function for block in CFHTTPCookieStorageFlushCookieStores() + 110
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b219f86 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b34b651 CFBasicHashApply + 113
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b219f4b CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 107
15  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x000000010abc3513 CFHTTPCookieStorageFlushCookieStores() + 133
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000011464b95d __cxa_finalize_ranges + 351
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000011464bc98 exit + 48
18  org.cocoapods.AutoLayout        0x000000010a9bf48b exitSignalHandler + 11
19  libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001148c2f5a _sigtramp + 26
20  ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001100d02ec lookUpImpOrForward + 360
22  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001100dd814 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
23  com.apple.UIAccessibility       0x000000013468fc08 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFindAnyAXDescendant:byAddingElements:] + 146
24  com.apple.UIKit.axbundle        0x000000013b848539 __60-[UITableViewAccessibility _delegateViewForHeaderInSection:]_block_invoke + 28
25  com.apple.accessibility.AXCoreUtilities 0x000000011a956aeb __55-[AXDispatchTimer afterDelay:processBlock:cancelBlock:]_block_invoke.43 + 65
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001144ee587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001144f0fac _dispatch_continuation_pop + 453
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001145013a1 _dispatch_source_invoke + 2037
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001144fa245 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 915
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b25d7f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257e86 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
33  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x0000000114e1f1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
34  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x000000011d4be115 UIApplicationMain + 140
35  appname         0x00000001097f5ba7 main + 71 (AppDelegate.swift:13)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000011455e551 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d4009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d4009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489420a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000114893724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b25d5c4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257bf9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1689
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010bb3f522 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010bb3f734 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 143
7   com.apple.UIKitCore             0x000000011d41863f -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 118
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010bb54932 __NSThread__start__ + 1221
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d4661 _pthread_body + 340
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d450d _pthread_start + 377
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d420e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bdc start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x7551746e656d656c 0 + 8453665993048024428

Thread 6:: JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489da16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d5589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000010a717821 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 93
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000011f8abdf5 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 117
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000011f8abcbf std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 95
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000011f8aa94e bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 254
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000011f8aa049 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 9
7   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000011f8abaa7 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 39
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d4661 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d450d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489420a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000114893724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b25d5c4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257bf9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1689
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x000000010ac90a2d -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 195
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010bb54932 __NSThread__start__ + 1221
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d4661 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d450d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bdc start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x000070000440db20 0 + 123145373670176

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bdc start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x00006000002ae2c0 0 + 105553119077056

Thread 10:: WebThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489420a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000114893724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b25d5c4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257bf9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1689
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010b257221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
5   com.apple.WebCore               0x0000000120d662b5 RunWebThread(void*) + 565
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d4661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d450d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000011489e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d420e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001148d3be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000003603  rbx: 0x0000000001010002  rcx: 0x00000001148c7a0c  rdx: 0x0000000000010001
  rdi: 0x0000000000003603  rsi: 0x0000000000003603  rbp: 0x00007ffee6784a90  rsp: 0x00007ffee6784a58
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x000000010b5ac328  r11: 0x00006000028686a0
  r12: 0x00000001109cfdd8  r13: 0x0000000000003603  r14: 0x0000000000003603  r15: 0x0000000000010000
  rip: 0x00000001148c55e2  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000011bf7d000
  
Logical CPU:     4
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?